# Creating document with 2 columns but do not spread one column to another in MS WORD

Tags: microsoft-word

I want to create document with 2 columns layout. I will fill first columns with article in English and second columns with translated article in another language. So text in column 1 should not go to column 2 if I reach bottom of page.

Can anyone help how to create such kind of document?

Thank you in advance.

HENDRA

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using columns, just use a two column table.  You can format the borders of the table to be invisible, and set the padding as you need it to maintain separation.

And this will roll over to new pages without issues, automatically.

Answer (score 0):

on MS Word go to the page layout click columns and then click the number of columns you want. then type as you continue typing when you get to the end of the 1st column, go to page layout and select breaks and then click continous ... this will breake your page and then you can start typing in the next column